# Submitting form from parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I would like to create a form where the submit button is located in the header. I'm currently using react-hook-forms but am having difficulties being able to submit the form from a component that is in the layout the displays the form (or child). I've included an image that may help visualize what im talking about.

[image]

Is there a way I can pass that form data or handleSubmit from react-hook-form to to the header that would then run the onSubmit when clicked?

Answer (score 15):

Just create a ref in the parent component, send it to the child component and assign that ref to an invisible submit button.

Finally, in the onClick event of the parent submit button simply call submitRef.current.click()

```
// ./From.js
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

// This is the child component with a ref received from the parent
// and assigned to an invisible submit button 
const Form = ({ submitRef }) => {
  const {register, setValue, getValues, ...other } = useForm();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      ...
      <button ref={submitRef} type="submit" style={{ display: 'none' }} />
    </form>
  );  
}; 


export default Form;
```

```
// ./Parent.js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Form from './Form'
 
const Parent = () => {
  const submitRef = useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => submitRef.current.click()}>Submit</button>
      <Form submitRef={submitRef}/>
    </>
  );  
}; 
export default Parent;
```

Comment: `submitRef.current` console logs undefined warning. But still this works. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably because the ref is not assigned yet...

Answer (score 6):

You can set ref on form:

`<form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>`

and then simulate onSubmit from any place:

`formRef.current.requestSubmit();`

This behaves as submit button click, without inserting unnecessary submit button: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is by raising the form state to the closest parent between the two components, then you can pass the change and submit handlers down to the requisite components.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

In the case of `react-hook-form` that means calling `useForm` in that highest shared component and passing down the functions, ideally using composition instead of prop drilling

Comment: Would this still be the case if there are multiple pages where forms are being used? For example, that picture above would be Settings > Profile, another would be Settings > Password where there is a password form.

Comment: Ideally you have different top level components for each page, and use the shared nav component via composition and pass in the submit handler (or none if there's no form!)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to investigate redux form and/or `connect()`

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 
const Form = ({ register, handleSubmit }) => {
  const methods = useForm();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(register)}>...</form>
  );  
}; 

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  register: (data) => dispatch(register(data))
});
 
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Form);

import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 
const Form = ({ register, handleSubmit }) => {
  const methods = useForm();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(register)}>...</form>
  );  
}; 
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Form);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
function handleForm(e) {
e.preventDefault()
// your code here
}

<button onClick={()=>{document.forms[0].submit()}} >Submit</button>

<form onSubmit={handleForm} >...</form>
```

For haters who dislike the answer:

```
const formRef=useRef();

function handleForm(e) {
e.preventDefault()
// your code here
}

<button onClick={()=>formRef.current.submit()} >Submit</button>

<form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleForm} >...</form>
```

Comment: Just because something works, doesn't mean it's correct. I downvoted you for giving the incorrect answer. That and you're not taking into account the form library OP is using

Comment: it works. It is not complicated. For normal situation; submit button should be inside form element. Abnormal situation=Abnormal solution. let me see your answer for this situation

Comment: @coagmano what is wrong with this approach if we are not using any form library?